# Installing Gnome 3, should I use gdm or lightdm?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, lightdm, gdm

I'm currently using Xubuntu 14.04 and I wanted to try out Gnome 3, so i started installing it, and during the installation it is asking me what display manager should I use by default: gdm or lightdm.
Which one should I use? if I chose one over the other will it affect in any way one of the two desktop environments (since I wanna keep both xfce and gnome)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both will work fine. You don't need both installed as `gdm` is a *recommends* dependency of `gnome-shell`, not a hard dependency. You can uninstall one or the other depending upon how you like them. I have used both with `gnome-shell` and faced no issues because of them.